# MySql Insert on duplicate Key update

Tags: mysql

I have a table say **content** table, having fields say

```
unitId | referenceId | contentId | masterContentId | sequence
```

Now I need to Insert on duplicate key update the values for sequence, referenceId fields with the values where `masterContentId` is say '10' and `contentId` is say '100', for the records where
`unitId` is say '500' and `contentId` is say '100'.
i.e.

```
rowId| unitId| referenceId | contentId | masterContentId | sequence|
-----+-------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+
1       10      1             500         2                a
2       20      2             300         4                b
3       500     3             100         6                c
4       500     4             700         8                d
5       30      5             100         10               e
6       40      6             100         20               f
```

So, what I was trying to explain is that, I need to update row number 3, with the corresponding values of row 5.

How to do it, using **Mysql Insert On duplicate Key Update**

Comment: Fiddle with your sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33137

Comment: The question is far from clear to me. What is the relation between row 3 and row 5 in your example? What “corresponding values” would these be? Which unique keys are defined for your table? Knowing those is essential when talking about duplicate key behaviour.

Comment: If you could put the desired end table in your question, that would be very helpful.